# Next.js After dynamic import, browser can not load ant.css with router

Tags: css, optimization, next.js, antd, dynamic-import

I'm doing optimization in Next.js project.
After I tried `dynamic import`, browser cannot load ant.d css with routing.

If guest users but try to access `https://mysitename.com/`(root) , it redirect to `https://mysitename.com/auth` and show login button(ant.d. component) which imported dynamically.
At this time browser can not load css.

But If I directly access page via url `https://mysitename.com/auth`, browser can load css.

And it also happen to paging accessing with `Link`.
If I access a page via `next/Link` component, browser can no load css. However If I directly access page via url, It can.

I also add `"sideEffects": false` on package.json
and this problem occured after build.

This is my `page/auth` and `page/index` code

// pages/auth.tsx

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro'

import { Footer } from '@/components/Footer'
import { MultiStepComponents } from '@/components/MultiStepComponents'

import { LoginProvider, useLooginContext } from './index.controller'

const KakaoFirstLogin = dynamic<{}>(() =>
  import('./components/KakaoFirstLogin').then((mode) => mode.KakaoFirstLogin),
)
const StandardLogin = dynamic<{}>(() =>
  import('./components/StandardLogin').then((mode) => mode.StandardLogin),
)
 
const Auth = () => {
  const { index } = useLooginContext()

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container>
        <LoginSectionWrapper>
          <LoginSection>
            <Header/>
            <MultiStepComponents index={index}>
              <KakaoFirstLogin />
              <StandardLogin />
            </MultiStepComponents>
          </LoginSection>
        </LoginSectionWrapper>  
      </Container>
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const AuthPage = () => {
  return (
    <LoginProvider>
      <Auth />
    </LoginProvider>
  )
}
```

//pages/index.tsx

```
import BaseLayout from '@/components/layouts/BaseLayout'

export default function HomePage() {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <LoggedRoute>
          <Menu />
          <Main/>
          <Footer />
      </LoggedRoute>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

//LoggedRoute

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import { useUserContext } from '@/context/userContext'

interface Props {
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
export const LoggedRoute = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const { logged } = useUserContext()
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!logged) router.replace('/auth')
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [logged])

  if (!logged) return null
  return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `KakaoFirstLogin` and `StandardLogin` components?

Comment: @juliomalves 
you can check `KakaoFirstLogin` and `StandardLogin` https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-oogz2
My whole project is so huge, I just copy some part of project. so It didn't run. 
I think it's tree shaking problem, but I don't know why only Ant.d css isn't loaded. other css is loaded well ... 